# get current date and time

Tags: android

I'm kind of stuck on date and time.
I want my program to create the date like this "20121217". The first 4 letters are the year, the second 2 letters are the month and the last 2 are the day. year+month+day

The time is "112233" hour+minute+second

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's a formatting issue.  Java uses `java.util.Date` and `java.text.DateFormat` and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` for those things.

```
DateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd hhmmss");
dateFormatter.setLenient(false);
Date today = new Date();
String s = dateFormatter.format(today);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
String date = c.get(Calendar.YEAR) + c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + c.get(Calendar.DATE);
String time = c.get(Calendar.HOUR) + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change any specific format of time or date as you need.

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
     currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
```

Answer (score 0):

For date:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
String strDate = df.format(new Date());
```

For time:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("hhmmss");
String strTime = df.format(new Date());
```

Answer (score 0):

This works,

```
 String currentDateTime;

 SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
 currentDateTime = sdf1.format(new Date());
```

Answer (score -1):

What you're looking for is the SimpleDateFormat in Java... Take a look at [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Try this for your need:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd hhmmss");
Date parsed = format.parse(new Date());
System.out.println(parsed.toString());
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use following method to get current time

```
 /**************************************************************
 * getCurrentTime() it will return system time
 * 
 * @return
 ****************************************************************/
public static String getCurrentTime() {     
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd HHmmss");
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    return dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
}// end of getCurrentTime()
```